# "Dynamic" template - Is it possible to change the actual templete while processing it?

Tags: freemarker

Suppose I have the following xml template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<myXML>
    <params>
      <param name="a"">${A}</param>
      <param name="b">${B}</param>
      <param name="c">${C}</param>
    </params>
</myXML>
```

I am looking for a way to change the template's cotnent based on a certing condition, for example:

```
if (<certain condition is true>)
{
     remove the line <param name="c">${C}</param> from the template
}
```

Please note: I am not looking to fill the value of ${C} but to remove this line from the template altogether. Sort of making the template "dynamic" rather than "static".

Of course I can hold two different tremplates and load the right one based on the condition but prefer the approach I described above if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A template can't change itself; the whole template is parsed before it's executed. But maybe it's easier to find a solution for the problem if the readers understand the problem. Why is `<#if <certain condition is true>><param name="c">${C}</param></#if>` not sufficient?

Comment: uhmmm that could work actually. I suppose I can populate the condition with true/false when I process the template.....